# Write base64 chunks into writestream

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, stream, base64

I establish a client/server socket connection with node.js v0.8. The client encodes a jpg into a base64 string and sends it to the server. The server is receiving those chunks and writes it into the writestream. After writing the data the new image file has the same size as the original image file but shows a corrupted message when i try to open it. Did i make something wrong with the base64 encoding or stream writing?

Client.js and Server.js snippet:

```
//Client sending base64 encoded string from image

var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var socket = new net.Socket();

socket.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/node.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});

    stream.on('data', function(chunk){
        socket.write(chunk, 'base64');
    });

});


//Server should write base64 string into new image file

var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var imageFilename = "node-copy.jpg";

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/node-copy.jpg', {flags: 'a',  encoding: 'base64'});    

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){  

  socket.setEncoding('base64');

  socket.on("data", function(chunk){
    writeStream.write(chunk, 'base64');
  });

}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to encode this as `base64`? From the code you have shown, there is no reason to.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I am using base64 because i want to stream a binary file. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Setting base64 means that the file is converted from binary into a string before being sent. Just leave out all of the encodings and it will be sent as binary by default.

Comment: @ loganfsmyth: I know this snippet make no sense but this is just a simplified example. The idea is to transmit the jpg data with a filename from the client to the server, everything as a base64 encoded string with a seperator. So i 
can split the data and create a jpg with filename on the server. But at first the base64 stream from the example must be properly written into the file.  Do you know how to accomplish this with the writestream?

Comment: What you are describing is sending a document + metadata in a stream. That is what HTTP is designed to accomplish, so I'd recommend that you use an HTTP connection and send the filename as a header which sending the image as the body.

Answer (score 1):

You're encoding each chunk as a separate entity, which is a wrong thing to do.

Use streaming base64 module like [this one](https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream).

Comment: Do you know a way how to code it without using 3rd party modules?

Comment: Yes. Write your own module that implements this functionality.